How to dynamically insert new tabs with the press of an input task button?
I am developing a Shiny app in Python and I am currently struggling to find a way to dynamically generate new tabs with the press of either an input task button or with a tab called "New". I've researched into using ui.insert_ui and achieved some level of the intended effect with dynamically adding panels to my ui.navset_tab but when clicking on the new tab, the tab freezes and I can't switch to the new tab.
Is there a more optimal way to create dynamic tabs and also remove them?
My code is outlined below:
from shiny import App, Inputs, Outputs, Session, reactive, render, ui
from shinywidgets import output_widget, render_widget

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.navset_tab(
        ui.nav_panel("Home",
              ui.card(
                          ui.card_header("Overview"),
                          ui.p("This is the landing page"),
                          ui.input_task_button(id = "create_tab",
                                               label = "Create New Tab",
                                               width = "400px",
                                               type = "success"),
                                )
                            ),
        id = "shiny_tabs"
    )
)

def server(input, output, session):

    # Set reactive values
    tabs_created = reactive.value(1)

     # Generate tabs
     @reactive.Effect
     @reactive.event(input.create_tab)
     def _():
          tab_title = f"View {tabs_created.get()}"
          ui.insert_ui(
              ui.navset_tab(
                  ui.nav_panel(tab_title,
                               ui.modal("This will include the accordion content")
                               )
                  ),
                  selector = "#shiny_tabs",
                  where = "beforeEnd"
          )
          
          tabs_created.set(tabs_created.get() + 1)
          
app = App(app_ui, server)

I also posted this question in posit-dev/py-shiny#1510.

I wouldn't use an ui.insert_ui approach here because it seems to make things too complicated. Instead you can use Shiny Modules. The below example basically consists out of these three parts:

A reactive.value navs which has an entry for each appended ui.nav_panel, e.g. nav.get() == [1, 2] if the button was clicked twice. It is similar to your tabs_created, but I use a list here.

A module.ui which is used for generating the new ui.nav_panel, it depends on the panel number:
@module.ui
def nav_panel_ui(panelNumber):
    tab_title = f"New tab {panelNumber}"
    return ui.nav_panel(
        tab_title,
        ui.p(f"Content of tab {panelNumber}"),
        value="panel" + str(panelNumber)
    )


A rendered ui.navset_tab (using on the server side render.ui and on the ui side ui.output_ui. The ui.navset_tab has this structure:
ui.navset_tab(
    ui.nav_panel("Home", ...), # your 'Home' tab, visible all the time

    # all additional nav_panels defined by navs.get()
    # the first parameter of nav_panel_ui is the id
    # '*' in order to pass the list values (nav_panels) to navset_tab()
    *[nav_panel_ui(str(x), panelNumber=str(x)) for x in navs.get()],

    .... # additional arguments
)



It looks like shown below. The remove functionality can be implemented similarly.

from shiny import App, reactive, module, render, ui


@module.ui
def nav_panel_ui(panelNumber):
    tab_title = f"New tab {panelNumber}"
    return ui.nav_panel(
        tab_title,
        ui.p(f"Content of tab {panelNumber}"),
        value="panel" + str(panelNumber)
    )


app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.output_ui("myUI")
)


def server(input, output, session):

    # Initialize reactive value which stores a list containing nav numbers
    navs = reactive.value([])

    # Set the list of nav values on button click
    # E.g. clicking the button twice sets navs = [1, 2]
    # Below this is used for rendering a list of tabs of the same length as navs
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.create_tab)
    def _():
        if len(navs.get()) == 0:
            navs.set(navs.get() + [1])
        else:
            navs.set(navs.get() + [max(navs.get()) + 1])

    # render the navset_tab, home tab + [nav_panel1, nav_panel2, ...]
    @render.ui
    def myUI():
        return ui.navset_tab(
            # the home tab
            ui.nav_panel("Home",
                         ui.card(
                             ui.card_header("Overview"),
                             ui.p("This is the landing page"),
                             ui.input_task_button(id="create_tab",
                                                  label="Create New Tab",
                                                  width="400px",
                                                  type="success"),
                         ),
                         value="panel0"
                         ),
            # all additional nav_panels defined by navs.get()
            # the first parameter of nav_panel_ui is the id
            # '*' in order to pass the list values (nav_panels) to navset_tab()
            *[nav_panel_ui(str(x), panelNumber=str(x)) for x in navs.get()],
            id="shiny_tabs"
        )


app = App(app_ui, server)


